# Add a number to a record in order to avoid duplicate values in a HashSet<Student>

Tags: c#, duplicates, .net-4.5

There is an Excel parser. It's supposed to take each first letter of student's names and create account names matching the following pattern se21XXX. For example. `John St. Jones` => `se21jsj`. Okay, but there might be another one with same name abbreviation/account name: `John St James` => `se21jsj`. It makes two of them with same account name.

I need to check if `accountName` already exists in `students` and if it does, it should add a number starting by 2 to the account name, if it still exists, it should go for 3 and so on. How do I do that?

For ex.

- John St. Jones => se21jsj
- John St James => se21jsj2
- John St Johny => se21jsj3
- and so on

```cs
public static void Parse(string filePath, InputSettings settings, Predicate<string> condition, ref HashSet<Student> students)
{
    using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
        {
            var result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration
            {
                //ConfigureDataTable = _ => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                //{
                //    UseHeaderRow = true
                //}
            });

            var sheet1 = result.Tables[0];

            for (var i = 0; i < sheet1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var specialtyName = sheet1.Rows[i][settings.SpecialtyColumn].ToString().Trim();

                if (condition(specialtyName))
                {
                    var facultyNumber = sheet1.Rows[i][settings.FacultyColumn].ToString();
                    var originalStudentName = Regex.Replace(sheet1.Rows[i][settings.NameColumn].ToString(), @"\s{2,}", " ");
                    var studentName = Transliteration.CyrillicToLatin(originalStudentName.ToUpper()).ToUpper();
                    var nameAbbreviation = string.Join("", studentName.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s.Substring(0, 1).ToLower()));
                    var accountName = $"{settings.SpecialtyAbbreviation}{facultyNumber.Substring(0, 2)}{nameAbbreviation}";

                    // TODO: Check if 'accountName' already exists in the students HashSet. If it does, add '2'. Example: se19shh2 => se19shh2
                    var duplicates = students.GroupBy(x => x.AccountName).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).ToList();

                    students.Add(new Student
                    {
                        AccountName = accountName,
                        FacultyNumber = facultyNumber,
                        StudentName = studentName,
                        OriginalStudentName = originalStudentName,
                        SpecialtyName = settings.SpecialtyName,
                        Abbreviation = settings.SpecialtyAbbreviation,
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `Dictionary<string, int>` for checking keys:

```
  // Known acronyms so far
  Dictionary<string, int> acronyms = 
    new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  ...

  string Acronym(string source) {
    string acronym = "se21" + string.Concat(source
      .Where(c => char.IsUpper(c))
      .Select(c => char.ToLower(c)));

    return (acronyms.TryAdd(acronym, 1))
      ? acronym
      : $"{acronym}{acronyms[acronym] += 1}";
  }
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] names = new string[] {
    "John St. Jones",
    "John St James",
    "John St Johny",
    "Poor Little Me",
    "Scrooge McDuck",
    "Charles de Batz de Castelmore d'Artagnan",
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, names
    .Select(name => $"{name,45} => {Acronym(name)}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
                           John St. Jones => se21jsj
                            John St James => se21jsj2
                            John St Johny => se21jsj3
                           Poor Little Me => se21plm
                           Scrooge McDuck => se21smd
 Charles de Batz de Castelmore d'Artagnan => se21cbca
```

**Edit:** In case of old versions of c# (without `TryAdd`)

```
  string Acronym(string source) {
    string acronym = "se21" + string.Concat(source
      .Where(c => char.IsUpper(c))
      .Select(c => char.ToLower(c)));

    if (acronyms.TryGetValue(acronym, out int count)) {
      acronyms[acronym] += 1;

      return $"{acronym}{count + 1}";
    }
    else {
      acronyms.Add(acronym, 1);

      return acronym;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! You suggest `Dictionary<string, Student>` to me, because of the `TryAdd` method, which would negate the need of that duplication check?

Comment: @nop: `TryAdd`  will do duplicate check for you (note, `Dictionary<string, int>`, not `Dictionary<string, Student>`)

Comment: `Dictionary<string, Student>` seems to not have `TryAdd` overload, because it's .NET Framework 4.0. I forgot to add that to the question.

Comment: @nop swap to using ContainsKey to see if the dictionary does know that key then. TryAdd is like `if(d.ContainsKey(x)) return false; else{ d[x] = y; return true; }` (you can use it as your own impl; turn it into an extension method, even)

Comment: @nop: in case of *old* c# version we can use `TryGetValue`, please, see my edit